# Patching together a Drupal project

Tags: 7

I'm trying to basicly glue/patch/fix a Drupal project so that I can edit it simpler. There's too much duplicated code which I want to make into the same function.

To do this I have to, from my own knowledge, handle `modules`. What I'm curious about is: What is the ideal way to structure these new functions?

Should I create a module called `global_fixes`, or should I add new functions to the existing modules? Feel free to share your solutions if you have been given a similiar situation.

Comment: Mostly in custom, I believe

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming that you inherited the custom modules along with the site, and there is no external maintainer of those, you should refactor the modules.

For contributed modules (i.e. modules maintained - or in some cases not - at drupal.org/projects), the options are more complicated.  I don't recommend creating yet another module (`global_fixes`) to deal with this.  You'll have problems keeping this in sync with new releases of the contributed modules you feel the urge to "fix".

Instead:

- If you're community oriented person, raise an issue in the module's project issue queue for what you consider duplicated code (or other defects). If you fix the problem yourself, make your fix a patch, and add the patch to the issue queue.
- If you don't want the hassle of dealing with module maintainers and the community, make a local fork where you essentially turn a contributed module into a custom one, and do whatever you like with it.  This also means that you will no longer be able to download improved versions of this module drupal.org/projects. You'll have to maintain it yourself (just like any other custom module).

If you want to follow the community route, you'll probably notice that not *all* Drupal project maintainers are prepared to resolve your issues or commit your patches in a timely manner.  So if you decide to create and submit patches, I strongly recommend that you install *git* and maintain a local repository that let you work with the code locally (independent of the repository at Drupal.org).  Just do a merge whenever there is a new commit available at the central repository.

If you're *really* community minded, and discover that all the fine patches you create and submit to a project's issue queue appearently fall into a black hole, you may want to read up on this: [Dealing with unsupported (abandoned) projects](http://drupal.org/node/251466).

Comment: I often prefer to do things on my own. Thanks for giving me an insight of the ideal workflow in Drupal contrib modules, but I think I'll be using more customs personally.